# Clearing a TextEditingController with the clear() method brings the focus back on the textfield

Tags: controller, keyboard, focus, edit

Clearing a TextEditingController with the clear() method brings the focus back on the textfield.
I do not want this behavior since it also pops the keyboard and I do not want that keyboard.
(1) I need to clear that textfield.
(2) I do not want the focus to move to it since it pops the keyboard.

One more thing, this occurs after I did a showdialog with choices.

Answer (score 0):

using FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode()) did the trick!
The keyboard disapear and the focus is now out of the textfield.